# A man is "seated" or "sitting" at a table?

Tags: word-choice, difference

A man is seated/sitting at a table, having a meal. He's the only customer.

Is there any difference between "seated" and "sitting" here? What is preferred?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between “was seated” and “was sitting”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/16799/difference-between-was-seated-and-was-sitting)

Comment: In Yorkshire, there is a third alternative, "sat", used exactly like _seated/sitting_.

Answer (score -1):

I'd say sitting because he's currently having a meal which implies he wasn't recently "seated".

Comment: _Seated_ can mean _in a sitting position_, saying nothing about how long the  sitter has been there.

Comment: Your'e welcome to say _sitting_, but your argument is specious.

Comment: Answers should be backed up with facts, not just contain opinions.